# Nodejs reference to class object from other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm learning nodejs now and Im wondering how can I reference to the object created in a other file

for example:
I have a file with my class **user.js** which I'm exporting

```
module.exports = class Username {

  constructor(name, lastProjects) {
    this.current.name = name;
    this.current.lastProjects = lastProjects;
  }

};
```

**name.handler.js** I can not export it this to oder files

```
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const User = require('../models/user.model');
module.exports = Alexa.CreateStateHandler(StatesConst.NAME, {
  'NewSession': function () {
    this.emit('NewSession'); // Uses the handler in newSessionHandlers
  },
  'MyNameIsIntent': function() {
    var user = new User.Username("Anna", ["project1", "project2"]);
    this.emit(':ask', "Hi "+User.Username.name);
    }
    }
```

**user.handler.js** I tottaly dont know how can I write a reference to my new created object Username

```
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const User = require('../models/user.model');
module.exports = Alexa.CreateStateHandler(StatesConst.NEWSTATE, {
  'NewSession': function () {
    this.emit('NewSession'); // Uses the handler in newSessionHandlers
  },
  'MyUserIntent': function() {
    this.emit(':ask', "My username is "+User.Username.name);
    }
    }
```

How can I reference to new user object in other files in my programm ? I want that everytime my user starts a program I will get a new user object and I could reference and change attributes in every other file. I would be very appreciate for a help :)

Comment: do you mean how to export and import class and use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    module.exports = Username;




const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk'); // ok?
const User =  // in linux, to go 1 dir up is just '.'
console.log(require('../models/user.model'))
```

see if you get a message = '[Function: Username]'".

If not you will see a message telling you something. Maybe no found file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are exporting `Username` by assigning it to `module.exports`, you need to use it as `new User` in your handlers. For example, **name.handler.js** would become:

```
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const User = require('../models/user.model');
module.exports = Alexa.CreateStateHandler(StatesConst.NAME, {
    'NewSession': function () {
        this.emit('NewSession'); // Uses the handler in newSessionHandlers
    },
    'MyNameIsIntent': function() {
        var user = new User("Anna", ["project1", "project2"]);
        this.emit(':ask', "Hi "+user.name);
    }
}
```

Note that in the `this.emit` line, you should use the instance of `User`, not the class itself. (so `user` instead of `User`).

Moreover, in your **user.handler.js** file, you don't instantiate any `User`. You will get a `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Finally if your `Username` class is in **user.js**, your require statement should look like `require('../models/user')`, not `require('../models/user-model')`

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Is it really not possible to get value user.name in  user.handler.js ? I would like that I get there the value which is defined in a file name.handler.js

Comment: To access `name` in **user.handler.js**, you need to find a way to expose it in **name.handler.js**: you need an instance of `User` to access its attributes. I'm not familiar with the `alexa-sdk` package, but it looks like you cannot share state/attributes between handlers. You might need to merge them. Can you take a look at their example and see if this might help you ? [Making Skill State Management Simpler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alexa-sdk#making-skill-state-management-simpler)